# Data is in the wrong format

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to insert data from my backend to MongoDb. For example if I want to insert  "2021-06-03" I will get "2021-06-02T21:00:00.000+00:00".
Model :

```
const organizerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
description: { type: String, required: true },
duration: { type: Number },
location: { type: String },
date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
```

And route :

```
const { description } = req.body;
const { date } = req.body;
const { location } = req.body;
const { duration } = req.body;


const newAdd = new Add({
  description,
  date,
  location,
  duration, 
 });
```

Comment: I suspect `{ date } = req.body;` is a string (not a Date object).

Comment: I have tried Date.parse() and it had the same result

Comment: Maybe use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) to convert the sting into a `Date` value (use `moment(req.body).toDate()`)

Comment: Same thing Wernfried

Answer (score 0):

try

```js
date: { type: Date, default: new Date() },
```

Comment: Same thing. It appers the date with 3 hours before. As I said if I want to show 30/05/2021 it will appear 29/05/2021T21:00:00:00. But if I don't enter any date, so it will be default, I got the exact date, not like 3 hours before

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try and saving it as a unix using moment ( moment().unix() )? This is a number and you should be able to easily convert it back to date.

Otherwise use moment to convert it to the proper timezone

moment(date).utcOffset('+0300').format(format)